# How do I remove a dynamically added series in highchart basic line chart?

Tags: highcharts

I can use this method to add a new series to the chart:

```
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'New Series',
        data: [551,233,3233]
    });
```

But I couldn't find a way to remove it. There is no `removeSeries` or `deleteSeries` functions in the API. How can I Do that?

Here is the code snippet:

```js
window.chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'U.S Solar Employment Growth by Job Category, 2010-2020'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="https://irecusa.org/programs/solar-jobs-census/" target="_blank">IREC</a>'
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    accessibility: {
      rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2020'
    }
  },

  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation & Developers',
    data: [43934, 48656, 65165, 81827, 112143, 142383,
      171533, 165174, 155157, 161454, 154610]
  }, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 37941, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282,
      38121, 36885, 33726, 34243, 31050]
  }, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 30000, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377,
      32147, 30912, 29243, 29213, 25663]
  }, {
    name: 'Operations & Maintenance',
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
      null, 11164, 11218, 10077]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [21908, 5548, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274,
      17300, 13053, 11906, 10073]
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});

$('#add_new').click(()=>{
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'New Series',
        data: [5551,2233,33233,23232,23232,54223]
    });
})
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p class="highcharts-description">
  <button id="add_new">Add New Series!</button>
    Basic line chart showing trends in a dataset. This chart includes the
    <code>series-label</code> module, which adds a label to each line for
    enhanced readability.
  </p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not any special API method for removing the series, but you can use vanilla JavaScript `remove()` method to achieve that.

```
  chart.series[index].remove();
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qv6ex7kL/

Comment: Is there any way I can set a "key" for reference rather than using an `index`?

Comment: Just FYI, I may have ten buttons, and each button refers to a group of data. I may add 1,4,5,7 and then remove 5 and 7.

Comment: Sure, you can e.g. set `id` to each series (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.id) and use it by `chart.get()` method . Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u5jczLhw/